# c language, extra message in stdout?

Tags: c, stdout

For some really odd reason my c program prints an extra message in the stdout, and I got no idea why is that.
assuming now that I insert 0,0,30 for stdin,the message in the stdout should be "auga", but if you compile the following code I bet you will be surprised for an extra message to appear, I am stunned and nor me nor my colleagues managed to spot why is that.

the code is as following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    system("chcp 1253");
    double a,b,g,temp,root1,root2;
    printf("Εισάγετε παρακαλω τιμες σταθερων α,β,γ για την εξίσωση αx^2+βx+γ=0 :\n");
    printf("Εισάγετε το α : ");
    scanf("%lf",&a);
    printf("Εισάγετε το β : ");
    scanf("%lf",&b);
    printf("Εισάγετε το γ : ");
    scanf("%lf",&g);
    if(a==0)
    {
        if((b==0)&&(g!=0))printf("auga\n");
        if((b==0)&&(g==0))
        {
            printf("Η συναρτηση είναι ταυτοτήτα καθώς α=0,β=0,γ=0 αρα αχ^2+βχ+γ=0 αφου 0+0+0=0");
        }
        else
        {
            temp=(float)g*-1;
            temp=(float)temp/b;
            printf("Η ριζα για την συναρτηση με α=0 ειναι : %.2lf ",temp);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        temp=(b*b)-4*a*g;
        if(temp>0)
        {   
        root1=((-b)+sqrt(temp))/(2*a);
        root2=((-b)-sqrt(temp))/(2*a);
        printf("οι ριζες που ισχυουν για αυτην την εξισωση ειναι οι αριθμοι : %.2lf,%.2lf ",root1,root2);
        }
        else if(temp==0)
        {
            root1=(-b)/(2*a);
            printf("Η ριζα που ισχυει για αυτην την εξισωση ειναι η : %.2lf  ",root1);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Η Σύναρτηση ειναι αδύνατη καθώς η διακρίνουσα ειναι μικρότερη του 0");
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. I cannot read your messages. What is the output and what was expected? Try using a debugger, you'll be surprised.

Comment: i  know you are unable to read my strings,but the problem was i was getting both if and else message,bellow i posted that i found the problem,debugger showed nothing i did give it a ride.
thank you for your time

Comment: I assume you are getting the word auga and then "printf("Η ριζα για την συναρτηση με α=0 ειναι : %.2lf ",temp);" 
b and g are not both zero, so the else is taken.

Comment: the `if` after `printf("auga\n");` should be **`else if`**. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the actual problem,turns out my instructor was wrong in one aspect,you see he told us that the line i had "else if" does not exist in c and it counts as an extra if,so as a good pupil i followed his advice,alas i found out that the problem lies with the actual second if,the code as fixed is as following and now works properly.
thank you for your time everyone sorry to bother you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    system("chcp 1253");
    double a,b,g,temp,root1,root2;
    printf("Εισάγετε παρακαλω τιμες σταθερων α,β,γ για την εξίσωση αx^2+βx+γ=0 :\n");
    printf("Εισάγετε το α : ");
    scanf("%lf",&a);
    printf("Εισάγετε το β : ");
    scanf("%lf",&b);
    printf("Εισάγετε το γ : ");
    scanf("%lf",&g);
    if(a==0)
    {
        if((b==0)&&(g!=0))printf("auga\n");
        else if((b==0)&&(g==0))
        {
            printf("Η συναρτηση είναι ταυτοτήτα καθώς α=0,β=0,γ=0 αρα αχ^2+βχ+γ=0 αφου 0+0+0=0");
        }
        else
        {
            temp=(float)g*-1;
            temp=(float)temp/b;
            printf("Η ριζα για την συναρτηση με α=0 ειναι : %.2lf ",temp);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        temp=(b*b)-4*a*g;
        if(temp>0)
        {   
        root1=((-b)+sqrt(temp))/(2*a);
        root2=((-b)-sqrt(temp))/(2*a);
        printf("οι ριζες που ισχυουν για αυτην την εξισωση ειναι οι αριθμοι : %.2lf,%.2lf ",root1,root2);
        }
        else if(temp==0)
        {
            root1=(-b)/(2*a);
            printf("Η ριζα που ισχυει για αυτην την εξισωση ειναι η : %.2lf  ",root1);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Η Σύναρτηση ειναι αδύνατη καθώς η διακρίνουσα ειναι μικρότερη του 0");
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```